# Producing an output for Ruby array

Tags: ruby, arrays, output

So i'm following a tutorial and I've generated the following code:

```
  1 my_array = [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ]
  2 
  3 odd_or_even = my_array.map do |element|
  3     element % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd"
  4 end
```

I just want to know how I can write an output type statement so I can test the code running the code in the command line.

Thanks.

Comment: google "ruby output" is too easy?

Comment: Sorry dude, I'm a total novice, you'll have to be patient with me

Comment: Seems weird that you'd be dealing with arrays in a tutorial and not have run across "puts"

Comment: Thank you for the working code snippet.  Would you consider omitting the line numbers?  They make it difficult for us to copy-paste your code into our editor in order to try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add as the last line

```
puts "Odd or even: #{odd_or_even}"
```

But if you're running in irb (command line) you could just type in the variable name and hit return

```
odd_or_even
=> ["odd", "even", "odd", "even", "odd", "even" "odd", "even", "odd"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code you have is in a file named: *starting_ruby.rb*:

1. Add a line to print the output at the end of the code like so: `puts odd_or_even`
2. Traverse to the specific location where the file exist in command line.
3. Run by typing the following in command line: `$ ruby starting_ruby.rb` (`$` is to signify the prompt, don't type it)
4. You should see the array you created with elements printed in separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging, [Kernel#p](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-p) is very handy.  It does an #inspect before printing the object, just like irb does:

```
my_array = [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ]

odd_or_even = my_array.map do |element|
    element % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd"
end
p odd_or_even
# => ["odd", "even", "odd", "even", "odd", "even", "odd", "even", "odd"]
```